# Nightwatch execute command, iteration

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I wonder if it is possible to implement what I want using `execute()` command provided by `Nightwatch.js`.

With `Nightwatch.js`, I want to perform an action on the table element multiple times base on the number of row it has. Obviously, my code doesn't work, anyone have a better idea on how to do it ?

```
// here is the execute() command
.exeute(
  function() {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr');
    return rows.length;  // suppose we have 3 rows in the table
  }, 
  [],
  function(result) {
    // here I want to perform an action to all the 3 rows, but I 
    // could not find a way to do that, here is my original thought
    for (let i = 1; i <= result; i++) {
      client.element('css selector', `table tbody tr:nth-child(${i})`, function() {
        // Action, do something here
      });
    }

  }
)
.waitForElementPresent('.mainpage', 15000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .elements to obtain a list of matched results and iterate through it.

```
.elements('css selector', 'td[class=someColumn]', (results) => {
          for(let i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++){
                client.elementIdText(results.value[i].ELEMENT, (element) => {
                       //do whatever you want with the element
                })
          }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the map() function, but the same idea with you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it all in the function called by execute?

```
// here is the execute() command
.exeute(
  function() {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr');
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      let row = rows[i];
      // Action, do something here
    }
  }
)
.waitForElementPresent('.mainpage', 15000)
```

Your original code might work if you update to reference `result.value` in your `for` loop to get the return value from the `execute` call.